# Docusign userStatus - enable/disable?

Tags: docusignapi

In Docusign documentation there is a DELETE method to change the userStatus to closed and i like to change the userStatus to enable/disable or active/deactive by using PUT/UPDATE method. Is there any other API/approach available for that?

Comment: Amit's answer below is correct. out of curiosity, what is your use case for wanting a status besides "closed"?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change userStatus to Active/Enable or Deactive/Disabled using API. Those are DS internal status and cannot be driven through APIs. Using APIs, you will add the user which will make userstatus as `ActivationSent` or you can close the user by calling `DELETE` method. Even through DS Web Console, you will not see any status as Disabled. When you do DELETE call on any user, in theory they are disabled to perform any activity on the DS Account, in other terms they are soft Delete.